# Hidden div to show up for 3 seconds and close on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a jquery or javascript to do this:

On page load the div will be hidden
then if I click a button the div will appear for 3 seconds and close

I found the example to auto hide a div after 3 seconds in this link http://papermashup.com/demos/jquery-divfade.html

and an example to show a div in this link http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show

How can I combine both example ? I need the div to be hidden on page load
only when a button is clicked then the div will appear for 3 seconds

This is what I have so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("div.mydiv").fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $("div.mydiv").remove();
        });
    }, 2000);

    $("#btnAddRow").click(function () {
        $("div.mydiv").show();
    });
});
</script>
```

The time out to fade out is working. But I need to set the div hidden in the beginning.
when I hide the div. The on click function does not seem to make it show up

the HTML

```
<div class="mydiv"  style="visibility: hidden; ">test</div>
```

I tried this too:

```
<div class="mydiv"  style="display: none;">test</div>
```

Comment: You are using `$("div.mydiv").remove();` So just think once div is removed. How it will be displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="mydiv"  style="display: none;">test</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#btnAddRow").click(function () {
    $("div.mydiv").show().delay(2000).fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("div.mydiv").remove();
```

change to:

```
$("div.mydiv").hide();
```